# 64 point FFT Hamming window interpolated to 720-point sequences

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

Can someone here explain the meaning of,  64 point FFT Hamming window interpolated to 720-point sequences and its inverse?

720 point is from 0 to $2 \pi$ or (0 to 720 degree). I get the 64 point hamming window. What I don't get is the interpolation to 720-point sequences. In what order should it be calculated?

Link to get more info the math and technology its not a problem just the FFT and its inverse.

What I am looking for is [the resultant plot or graph is fig 18 on page 43](https://dspace.lib.cranfield.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1826/773/Acoustics_of_racing_engine_intake_systems-2004.pdf;sequence=4).

I add this to answer A_A and make it more clear.
And the fact he made my mind more clear about the (hamming window) typo!.
Skuld have been moving Hanning window.
As A_A pointed out i may have been confused why it was implemented.
yes and no is my answer to that clearly it shows the variations in the, 
Intake pressure when valve is both open and closed that is one part of the "problem" i have.
The other "problem" witch is also related to the same issue a wave and pressure.
When the valve is closed the intake air will hit a wall and punchback and usual we say.
4 waves. One cycle of the intake stroke is total 720 degree.

In between the opening of the valve. Lets say engine rpm is 18000, 60 sec / rpm = 0.0033 sec.

i forgot to mention before ivo (intake valve open) ivc (intake valve closed) in between we have
180 crankshaft degree tdc(piston strait up) degree = 0 bdc(piston at bottom) degree = 180

and we can set camshaft lobe center to 108 after tdc

crankshaft ivo = 20 degree before tdc + 180 and ivc 50 degree after bdc.
here is also one important thing camshaft rotate 1/2 the speed of crankshaft.

camshaft opening is 250 degree time closed is 720-250 = 470 / 360 1.30 revolution = 0.0043 sec
Speed of sound in air at 30 degrees Celsius is 349.08 m/sec 0.0043 sec time * speed of sound wave length 1.05 meter
impossible to take care of in a car. So shorten to 1/4 the final length is then 0.37598825 meter 
Normal referred to as quarter of a wave, witch is the last of the 4 waves.
When that arrives at the valve i want that to be a sinusoidal wave and know its frequency.
Why? it tells me howe fast the intake valve needs to move,
along with what is pointed out in 3.3 The acoustics of the intake system.
The pressure is not constant during the intake stroke, also important to know.
First time i have seen fft used in context of intake flow.
So if any other suggestion i will be happy to listen and also code it.

Hope you can help

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify the point of the question please? For example, you could add some pseudocode that shows what you are trying to do, what you expected and what you are actually getting. From what is described here, my understanding is that you have a 64-point sequence and you want to "expand" it to 720 points (?) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is what I do not really get. One cycle of the intake stroke is total 720 degree. In between the opening of the valve. Lets say engine rpm is 18000 60 sec / rpm = 0.0033 sec. cam opening is 250 degree time closed is 720-250  = 470 / 360 1.30 revolution = 0.0043 sec Speed of sound in air at 30 degrees Celsius is 349.08 m/sec 0.0043 sec time * speed of sound wave length 1.05 meter impossible to take care of In a car. so shorten to 1/4 the final length is then 0.37598825 meter when the wave arrives at the valve opening and the pressure is what it is about. Normal calculation on the wave.

Comment: So what you are looking at is an air wave punching up and downing the intake manifold. And change with different rpm. But converted to hertz and sinusodal curve.  I hope that helps. To me it seems the opposite but I could be wrong. and almost certainly I am.

Comment: OK, that is a bit more clearer. Can I please ask you to include these details in the body of the question along with a very brief description of what you are trying to do and how is the hamming window related to that? The reason I am saying this is because, my perception from what I read is that you may have confused why the window is applied at that point. But to provide some answer, we need a little bit more detail. Don't worry about mentioning technical details from the problem you are dealing with, the more the better, so that we can understand what exactly the "problem" is here.

Comment: hope It's more clear now other info  I have to ask you to contact I private then it's secrets

Comment: OK, I **think**, I understand what the problem might be. But first we need to clarify one thing: The hamming window does not represent the wave "pulse" you are looking for. Other than this: Do you have a single microphone or other sensors on the engine? Why do you focus on the intake pressure wave?

Comment: I don't have a microphone yet nor do I think I need it. Sens i have never sen fft used in this context it surprise me.
why focus on the intake wave?. Sens the engine you looking at is a non turbo or any other blower that force air mixture in to the cylinder. 
what do you have to work with? the pressure that surround you.
Standard sea-level pressure. by definition, equals 760 mm (29.92 inches) of mercury.
That is max pressure in order to fill the cylinder have to focus on the intake wave.
i am interested in the mathematical solution. I have added a few things in the body of the question.